# how to access lower channel using Actioncable client?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I am using this action cable library https://github.com/hosopy/actioncable-client-java  in an Android app, I have been able to make a connection with the top channel. However, I cannot seem to access lower channels. This is how my endpoint looks http:/endpoint/domains/1/subjects.

I am able to access the "DomainsChannel", but does anyone know how can I pass the domain id 1 and access the subjects channel?

```
    ws:/endpoint/domains/1/subjects

    Channel subjectsChannel = new Channel("DomainsChannel");
```

Answer (score 1):

The way how you can pass additional parameters into `ActionCable` channels described [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#passing-parameters-to-channel).

From within Rails project it's enough to pass channel name and additional params in the following way:

```
{ channel: "DomainsChannel", id: "domain-id-here" }
```

But from the third party clients (such as Android and iOS) you need to do a little trick to subscribe to the ActionCable's channel.
Once connection with the WebSocket is established you can send message with a following content to subscribe to that channel:

```
{
  "command":"subscribe",
  "identifier":"{\"channel\":\"DomainsChannel\"}"
}
```

Pay attention that `"identifier"` value is a string, **not a JSON** it is a **string** which looks like JSON.

So I suppose you can extend the `"identifier"` to have `id` inside:

```
{
  "command":"subscribe",
  "identifier":"{\"channel\":\"DomainsChannel\",\"id\":\"domain-id-here\"}"
}
```

Originally my thoughts was described in my [blog post](http://ck3g.github.io/2016/12/19/rails-and-action-cable.html).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @ck3g, I will try this out asap.